# HTTPS traffic from SharePoint in Fiddler not available

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, https, fiddler

I have SharePoint 2010 Foundation installation and custom web part which makes some external service calls over HTTPS. Calls are made in SharePoint by service account (RuninigWithElevatedPriviledges). I want to record those HTTPS calls in Fiddler but cannot see them.

These are things that I have already checked:
- Installed HTTPS certificate in Fiddler and enabled HTTPS logging and decryption
- Running application pool under currently logged in windows user
- Running Fiddler as administrator

What else I could check? Service calls are actually made (I can see tunnel logs in Fiddler), but cannot decrypt them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Fiddler is seeing the CONNECT tunnels, but no traffic is going over them, and decryption is enabled, then the service is most likely not trusting the Fiddler root certificate.

Use MMC.exe to launch the Certificate Manager for the MACHINE account and import the FiddlerRoot.cer into the Trusted Store for the machine account.